# Can I say to the CBP I am visiting my boyfriend in the USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I am from Latin America and I am planning to visit my boyfriend in the US for 33 days. Can I tell the CBP I am visiting my boyfriend when they ask "why are you coming to the US?".

The first time I went to the US, I spent 3 weeks there with my family, then I was in the US for 12 months in a exchange program. I met my boyfriend there. Now, after almost 1 year living in my home country I decided to visit my boyfriend for 33 days. I am working in my country. I don't know what to say when they ask why I am visiting.

Comment: Are you Chilean? If not, a large part of the scrutiny was performed during the visa interview, so unless you lied during the visa interview, saying the same thing to the CBP should be just fine

Comment: No I am from Peru, I ask for my visa 4 years ago. I had not met my boyfriend at that time. I am scared. I am spending a lot of money on the ticket and really want to go see him. But I am scared the CBP would think I want to get married or something.like that. I am not planning to do that.

Comment: When they ask why you are visiting you tell them why you're visiting... which is to see your boyfriend. Lying to immigration or customs agents is  a Very Bad Idea™.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are your choices between truthfully saying you are visiting your boyfriend and lying? There is no harm in visiting a friend. Be able to prove you'll return home. That means things like:

- I have a job at home, I have been given X days off for this trip and then I will go back to it (a letter from an employer can help)
- I am starting a program of study at home after this trip, here is the letter of acceptance and whatever other paperwork I have about where I will live etc
- My parents/siblings/family are all at home and I live with them, look after them, etc, here is a list of everyone's names and why I couldn't possibly move away from them

Lying to the CBP is not a good strategy. It probably won't work (they are trained to detect this sort of thing) and it will get you banned. Understand what they want to know, and have that information for them.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am not planning to overstay. I just want to go visit him. I am scared maybe the CBP would think I want to oversay and get married, but I am not planning that

Comment: Right, so the way you show them you won't overstay is you show them what will take you back home. If you start the whole thing with lying, what on earth will make them believe you when you say you aren't planning to overstay? I know it's not possible to be sure they will believe you. But gather your proof, remind yourself of your truths, and tell them all that when they ask.

Comment: Isn't the return ticket another usual piece of evidence that you want to return home?

Comment: @AytAyt Do you think nobody with a job or family at home ever overstayed? The round trip ticket is just one more piece of evidence, but obviously there's no 100% sure way to prove that you plan to leave on time. The more support you can show for that, the better.

Answer (score 1):

You should plan on visiting families and friends, and when asked you should say you are planning on visiting families and friends.

You don't lie, but you don't have to volunteer things that would invite even more questions.  You are planning on returning home, you should be confident that things will go according to plan.